# How do you make light?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, temperature

We make light making a charge oscillate, or heating a body. Are there differences between the two processes?

But, above all, are there other ways in which we can produce em radiation?

Comment: Electrons transitioning between atom energy levels can emit photons. Used cleverly, this gives us LASERs. I would not classify this phenomenon as either a charge oscillating or the heating of a body, but one can always nitpick.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  energy level transitions are most certainly **not** oscillations; nor are they heating.  Heating a bunch of matter involves particle motion aka phonons.

Comment: Heating is just the easiest, brute force way way to impart energy to an electron so rises then drops energy levels to make photons. Like making sound by banging and thrashing everywhere instead of carefully making sound with an instrument or speaker.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, we agree.

Comment: ... of a situation?    :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanta of em radiation called photons are produced in many reactions involving fundamental particles, atomic nuclei or whole atoms. These include thermal vibration of atoms and molecules; transition of a molecule, an atom or an orbital electron from an excited state to a lower energy state; particle-antiparticle annihilation; nuclear fusion; nuclear fission; and decay of unstable particles. Not all of these processes produce photons in the visible light range.

Comment: how does heat produce light?

Comment: @user157860 Either thermal vibrations of atoms and molecules or transitions of an orbital electron from an excited state to a lower energy state.

Answer (score 1):

How about an AC electric circuit attached to an antenna - like any radio, cellular, or TV transmission tower.   Granted it takes a bit of work :-) to make an oscillator in the visible-spectrum frequency range, but it's all the same principle.

Comment: that was my first option, but it'd hard to make electron go up and down 400 tera times a second. Do you know what is the actual distance an e- covers in one oscillation and if it depends on the frequency?